# implementing conditionals in shell (&& and ||)

Tags: bash, conditional-statements

I'm trying to implement the && and || operators of the bash shell for an assignment - in C. For an input like:

`a && b && c`

my parser makes a linked list with "symbol" and "connector" i.e.:

`a - &&`

`b - &&`

`c - END`

so I can evaluate the symbol to determine whether to check the next condition or not. I know the basic idea, but is there a general algorithm for how to implement the conditionals? Mainly, if somebody passes in something like `a && (b | c) || d && e || f`, then I just don't know what's a good way to attack that. I tried evaluating the first symbol and storing status to check what to read next, but it's not a good approach.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I presume the `|` is a typo. Or are you supposed to parse the `|` (aka pipe) operator too?

Comment: Well, that means the parser I wrote for you will need to be a bit more complex because there will be another operator with another precedence level. I'm just glad you're not handling redirects and some of the other interesting bash syntax. The parser could get really hairy really quickly, and you might have to use a more formal means to write it. Anyway, is my answer helpful to you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The general method for implementing this results in a syntax tree, not a list. You need to parse the list of tokens (which is what you've created) into an AST (Abstract Syntax Tree) describing the expression.

There is no way to get the precedence right with the way you're doing it now. And this is crucial for the short-circuit evaluation property the `&&` and `||` operators have.

Here is some sample code in Python that will build your tree structure. It's kinda ugly, and I would write a prettier parser if I were really doing this. This is just to give you the general idea:

```
def parsellst(lst):
    stack = []
    for tok in lst:
        if tok == '(':
            if (len(stack) > 0) and (stack[-1] not in ('&&', '||')):
                raise RuntimeError("Malformed expression")
            stack.append(tok)
        elif tok == ')':
            while (len(stack) >= 4) and (stack[-2] != '('):
                if stack[-2] not in ('&&', '||'):
                    raise RuntimeError("Malformed expression")
                node = (stack[-2], stack[-3], stack[-1])
                stack[-3:] = [node]
            if (len(stack) <= 1) or (stack[-2] != '(') or \
                    (stack[-1] in ('&&', '||')):
                raise RuntimeError("Malformed expression")
            stack.pop(-2)
        elif tok == '||':
            if len(stack) <= 0:
                raise RuntimeError("Malformed expression")
            elif stack[-1] in ('&&', '||', '('):
                raise RuntimeError("Malformed expression")
            while (len(stack) >= 3) and (stack[-2] != '('):
                node = (stack[-2], stack[-3], stack[-1])
                stack[-3:] = [node]
            stack.append(tok)
        elif tok == '&&':
            if len(stack) <= 0:
                raise RuntimeError("Malformed expression")
            elif stack[-1] in ('&&', '||', '('):
                raise RuntimeError("Malformed expression")
            if (len(stack) > 1) and (len(stack) < 3):
                raise RuntimeError("Malformed expression")
            while (len(stack) >= 3) and (stack[-2] not in ('(', '||')):
                node = (stack[-2], stack[-3], stack[-1])
                stack[-3:] = [node]
            stack.append(tok)
        else:
            stack.append(tok)
    while len(stack) > 1:
        if len(stack) < 3:
            raise RuntimeError("Malformed expression")
        if stack[-2] == '(':
            raise RuntimeError("Malformed expression: missing )")
        else:
            node = (stack[-2], stack[-3], stack[-1])
            stack[-3:] = [node]
    if len(stack) > 0:
        return stack[-1]
    else:
        return ()
```

The tree structure this code builds is very lispish. Each node of your tree consists of a 'tuple' (sort of like a lisp list) in Python that looks like `(operator, arg1, arg2)`. It's up to you to figure out how to use it. As a hint, you would have to write an evaluator that processed the tree in a particular order.

Also, this parser drops the parenthesis because it treats the parenthesis as merely a grouping construct. But for `bash` this isn't wise because parenthesis have meaning beyond mere grouping. So the thing should be modified (which is relatively trivial) to put the 'parenthesis operator' back into the resulting tree.

Here's an example of how to use the parser and what it's output looks like:

```
>>> parsellst(['a', '&&', '(', 'b', '||', 'c', ')', '||', 'd', '&&', 'e', '||', 'f'])
('||', ('||', ('&&', 'a', ('||', 'b', 'c')), ('&&', 'd', 'e')), 'f')
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a parsing tree: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parse_tree

I have made an example of a tree you could use here: http://csclub.uwaterloo.ca/~mtahmed/parse.txt

In this txt file, the `\` character is the link, `-` characters make the branches, the letters make up the variables, and everything else is operators like `&&` and `|` and `||` etc.

Also, note that since there is short-circuiting, you can add checks inside your parsing function to see if something has been short-circuit and stop. So e.g. if you see that `a` is false and the next operator is `&&`, then stop parsing and return false.

Comment: In bash `&&` has a higher precedence than `||`, so your parse tree isn't correct for the sample expression the OP gives.